# Projective space prolongation of a rationnal map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, rational-functions

I know very little about algebraic geometry and I apologize for a very vague question.

I have a reminiscence of a theoreme saing that in a projective variety you can prolongate any partially defined injective rational map on the entire variety.

Is there any real theorem that would state something like this ?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The closest one has says if you have a Zariski open set $U\subset X$, where $X$ is a non-singular curve and $f:U\to Y$ a morphism with $Y$ projective, then one can extend this to all of $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !

If both $X$ and $Y$ are projectives varieties and $f$ is a rational map partially defined on $X$ and with values in $Y$, can we prolongate $f$ to $X$ entirerly ?

Sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: Not in general. In general works only for $X$ a non-singular curve. Think of the map $\mathbb{P}^2\to\mathbb{P}^1$, given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y)$. It is a rational map outside the point $(0,0,1)$, but can not be extended.